# Probability question with conditions

Tags: probability

A particular car manufacturer has three factories $F1$, $F2$, $F3$ making $26\%$, $35\%$, and $39\%$, respectively, of its cars. Of their output, $7\%$, $5\%$, and $1\%$, respectively, are defective. A car is chosen at random from the manufacturer’s supply:

What is the probability that the car is defective?

Given that the car is defective, what is the probability that it came from factory F1?

Having a hard time understanding these. Please explain this to me

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Using the [law of total probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) we have
$$
P(\text{defective})=\sum_i P(\text{defective}\mid \text{from }\; F_i)P(\text{from }\; F_i).
$$

To find $P(\text{from }\; F_1\mid\text{defective})$ you can use [Bayes' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#Simple_form) since you've just calculated $P(\text{defected})$.

Answer (score 0):

The chance that a random car is from F1 is 0.26. The chance that that car is defective is 0.26*0.07 = 0.0182. Likewise, the chance that a car is from F2 and is defective is 0.35*0.05 = 0.0175 and the chance that the car is from F3 and defective is 0.39*0.01 = 0.0039.

The chance that any given car is from one of these three factories and defective is just the sum of all of these probabilities, so 0.0182+0.0175+0.0039 = 0.0396, or about 4%.

Figuring out whether a given defective car is from F1 is a bit trickier and we need to invoke Bayes Theorem. Bayes Theorem states that

$$
P(\text{A}\mid\text{B})= \frac{P(\text{B}\mid\text{A})P(\text{A})}{P(\text{B})}
$$

Where P(A) means "probability that A is true" and P(A|B) means "probability that A is true, given that B is true." We want to find the probability that a car is from F1 given that it is defective, so A = "car is from F1" and B = "car is defective."

From the previous work and the given information, we know a few things that are relevant here.

- P(B): The probability that the car is defective is 3.96%
- P(A): The probability that a car is from F1 is 26%
- P(B|A): The probability that a car is defective given that it is from F1 is 0.07%

We can just plug these numbers into the formula and we get that 
$$
P(\text{A}\mid\text{B})=\frac{P(\text{B}\mid\text{A})P(\text{A})}{P(\text{B})}=\frac{\left(0.01820\right)\left(0.07\right)}{0.0396}=0.032\overline{17}
$$

So the chance that that a given defective car came from F1 is about 3.2%.